# Вживання слова "завоювати" стосовно певного стилю

Tags: вживання-слів, семантика

Треба відредагувати речення:

> Рюші й шлярки поступово завойовують навіть офісну моду, з'являючись на досить строгих сорочках і спідницях.

Особисто мені ріже вухо сполучення "завойовують моду". У [Словнику української мови онлайн](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=28174&page=939) жодне значення слова "завойовувати" не відповідає наведеному випадку вживання. До того ж, чи можуть елементи одягу здійснити "наступ" на сферу власного існування? Як краще побудувати речення?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Часткова відповідь

Мені здається, що наведений контекст цілком вписується в типові випадки застосування слова «завойовувати». Просто в словнику переносні значення слова «завойовувати» описані доволі скупо.

- «Завойовувати» використовують як синонім до «здобувати».

  > Рюші й шлярки **завоювали [здобули] прихильність** мільйонів.
  >   Рюші й шлярки **завоювали [здобули] популярність** навіть у компаніях зі строгим дрес-кодом.
  >   Рюші й шлярки **завоювали [здобули]** широке **визнання**.

  Так, зазвичай «завойовувати (здобувати)» передбачає докладання зусиль, але хто сказав, що дизайнери, виробники і маркетологи, що стоять за цією продукцією не докладали величезних зусиль (тобто рюші й шлярки не самі собою, а рюші й шлярки як результат (уособлення?) діяльності певних людей).
- «Завойовувати» іноді виступає як синонім до «підкоряти»/«захоплювати»/«полонити» («заполоняти»), беручи додатком іменник, що позначає певну «територію».

  > Ця продукція **завоювала ринок**.
  >   Цей стиль **завоював світ** офісної моди.

Джерела:
1. «Right Neighbour Cooccurrences» для [слова «завоювали» в корпусі «ukr_mixed_2014» у «Leipzig Corpora Collection»](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8).
2. Синоніми для слів «здобувати» і «підкоряти» у [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).

У словнику обидва вищенаведені аспекти підпадають під не дуже ретельно описане переносне значення (2):

> 2. *що*, *перен[осне значення]*. У боротьбі, праці, переборюючи труднощі і т. ін., досягати, добиватися чого-небудь, здобувати щось. *<…>* // *кого*. Перетягувати на свій бік, привертати до себе кого-небудь. *<…>*

Незважаючи на (на мою думку) недостатньо пропрацьовані визначення, словник містить-таки приклади, де завойовують не люди, а абстрактні поняття, що є уособленням діяльності людей:

> – **Нове** ніколи не вилуплюється, мов курча з яйця. Новому доводиться **завойовувати** собі право на існування (Ю. Шовкопляс);
>   Без напасті **завоює** [**правда**] Города і села, І над людьми зацарює, Приступна й весела (П. Куліш).

#### Але

Я не впевнений, що слово «мода» є доречним додатком для «завойовувати» (принаймні у цьому контексті). Для мене не звучить ані як іменник на позначення позитивного ставлення людей (як от: «довіра», «симпатія» тощо), ані як іменник на позначення чогось, що можна асоціювати з територією і відповідно завойовувати. І тому (і саме тому, а не через використання слова «завойовувати») мені ця фраза трішки ріже слух. Але я не кажу, що я правий. Можливо, я просто недостатньо стикався з переносними значеннями слова «[мода](http://sum.in.ua/s/moda)».